# Finding the volume of the solid generated by revolving about the y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

The two functions are:

$f(x)= 4x$ and $f(x) = 2x^2$

I found the POI at x= 0 and x=2. From the graph I drew I can tell its a washer so I did,

$V=\pi \int _{\:0}^2\:\left(\left(2x^2\right)^2\:-\:\left(4x\right)^2\right)\:dx$

After computing I got a really large number which doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the shell method, you would get

$\displaystyle V=\int_0^2 2\pi r(x)h(x)\;dx=\int_0^2 2\pi x(4x-2x^2)dx=4\pi\int_0^2(2x^2-x^3)dx$

---

Alternatively, the disc method gives

$\displaystyle V=\int_0^8 \pi\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)^2\right)dy=\int_0^8\pi\left(\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{16}\right)dy$

Answer (score 0):

$$V = \pi \int_{0}^{8} \left[(\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}})^2- (\frac{y}{4})^2\right]dy$$
Thanks

Satish

Comment: So if it says it is revolving around the y-axis you use the function in terms of x, and if it said x-axis you use in terms of y?